# Can't get DisambiguateRecordFields to work

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I'm trying to use DisambiguateRecordFields to allow me to use the same field name in different records, but I can't get it to work.  For example:

-- File A.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE DisambiguateRecordFields #-}

module A where

data ARec = ARec {nID :: Int, sDesc :: String}
```

-- File B.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE DisambiguateRecordFields #-}

module B where

data BRec = BRec {nID :: Int, sProdCode :: String}
```

-- File Main.hs

```
{-# LANGUAGE DisambiguateRecordFields #-}

module Main where

import A

import B

zA = ARec 123 "Happy"

zB = BRec 456 "Usually"

main = putStrLn $ "zA's ID is " ++ show (nID zA)
```

If I write the above three files and :load Main into GHCi it complains about the collision on nID.  I thought this was precisely what DisambiguateRecordFields was designed to overcome.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks, Ian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DisambiguateRecordFields` only works for some cases, while others still are ambiguous (or at least are considered ambiguous, even if that's sometimes not actually true). See [the relevant documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#disambiguate-fields), specifically "bad2" among the examples there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see the relevance. In my code zA is unambiguously typed as ARec via the use of the constructor. In bad2 k is genuinely ambiguous.  Incidentally the problem persists even if I add explicit type declarations zA :: ARec and zB :: BRec.

Comment: True, but that's the part in parentheses: still _considered_ ambiguous. `DisambiguateRecordFields` just doesn't handle that case. There are some proposals for further extensions that might help with the remaining cases, though: http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records

Comment: Thanks chirlu.  What I think you're saying that it's a limitation of what is in any case an extension to the base language.  I guess I'm disappointed that this extension does so very little; I don't think it will help me at all in what I'm doing.  Oh well, I'd better get standardising my field names apart!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, `DisambiguateRecordFields` only works when importing from other modules, as you rightly did it. So one can easily reimport just the field name qualified and use it where the compiler fails

```
{-# LANGUAGE DisambiguateRecordFields #-}

module Main where
import A
import B
import qualified A as A(nID)

zA = ARec 123 "Happy"
zB = BRec 456 "Usually"

main = putStrLn $ "zA's ID is " ++ show (A.nID zA)
```

other occurrences left to the compiler.